# how to convert projection x and y coordinate in netcdf iris cube to lat lon

Tags: python, netcdf, python-iris

see question above, just want to get lat/lon for Google maps from Iris cube...

> cube.coord_system()

LambertAzimuthalEqualArea(latitude_of_projection_origin=54.9, longitude_of_projection_origin=-2.5, false_easting=0.0, false_northing=0.0, ellipsoid=GeogCS(semi_major_axis=6378137.0, semi_minor_axis=6356752.314140356))

[image]

Comment: If you just want to get the latitudes and longitudes for the cube grid points and not for arbitrary points, you can probably also use `cube.coord('latitude').points` and `cube.coord('longitude').points`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only want to transform x- and y-coordinates to plot the data, you can use `iris` and `cartopy`:

```py
import iris
import numpy as np
```

First, get coordinate points in the native projection

```py
proj_x = cube.coord("projection_x_coordinate").points
proj_y = cube.coord("projection_y_coordinate").points
```

Next, make a pair of 2D arrays with the same shape

```py
xx, yy = np.meshgrid(proj_x, proj_y)
```

Then extract the native projection and convert it to a `cartopy` projection:

```py
cs_nat = cube.coord_system()
cs_nat_cart = cs_nat.as_cartopy_projection()
```

Next, create a target projection, e.g. the standard ellipsoid projection

```py
cs_tgt = iris.coord_systems.GeogCS(iris.analysis.cartography.DEFAULT_SPHERICAL_EARTH_RADIUS)
# Again, convert it to a cartopy projection
cs_tgt_cart = cs_tgt.as_cartopy_projection()
```

And finally, use `cartopy`'s transform method to convert the 2D coordinate arrays in native projection to coordinates in the target projection.

```py
lons, lats, _ = cs_tgt_cart.transform_points(cs_nat_cart, xx, yy).T
# Note the transpose at the end.
```

Also note that the function above always returns `z` coordinate array, but in this case is 0.

You can then use `lons` and `lats` to plot your data in Google Maps or other applications. Remember that these new coordinates are curvilinear, so in practical terms have to be 2D arrays.

If you, however, want to plot the data in `iris` (and `matplotlib`), you can do it this way:

```py
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


proj_x = cube.coord("projection_x_coordinate").points
proj_y = cube.coord("projection_y_coordinate").points
cs_nat_cart = cube.coord_system().as_cartopy_projection()

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection=ccrs.PlateCarree())
ax.pcolormesh(proj_x, proj_y, cube.data, transform=cs_nat_cart)
ax.coastlines()
```

Hope this helps.